# Python -> 2D list changing at every index?

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, indexing, 2d

I've created 28 char array `seq`, and copied it 100 times to other array `copies`.

Now at each copy I'd like to change one random char to the other one - `def mutate()`.
It works when it is not in "for". When I try to do it for every copy (for i in range (0, 99) ) it changes copy not only at "i" index but every copy (index) in `2D` array "copies".

Why it works like this or how to change it? Why it doesn't change only at current index "i"?

```
import random

    def rand():
        a = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMANOPQRSTUWVYZ '
        alphabet = list(a)
        seq = []
        for i in range (0, 27):
            seq.append(alphabet[random.randint(0,26)])
        copies = []
        for i in range (0, 99):
            copies.append(seq)
        #print (alphabet)
        print(copies[10])
        s="".join(seq)
        return copies, alphabet


    def mutate(copies, alphabet):

        print(copies[10])
        for i in range(0, 99):
            tmp = random.randint(0,26)
            copies[i][tmp]=alphabet[random.randint(0,26)]
            print(copies[10])
        print(copies[10])


    copies, alphabet = rand()
    print(len(copies))
    #print(copies[10])
    #print(copies[11])
    mutate(copies, alphabet)
    print(len(copies))
```

Comment: `copies.append(seq)` does not actually copy anything, it just appends an already existing object..

Comment: as this question is closed, but I had already the full working example prepared: https://megastore.uni-augsburg.de/get/cMwgYVcYFW/